# Kubernetes service ip isn't always accessible within cluster (with flannel)

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I built a kubernetes cluster, using flannel overlay network. The problem is one of the service ip isn't always accessible.

I tested within the cluster, by telneting the **service ip** and port, ended in connection timeout. Checked with netstat, the connection was always in "SYN_SENT" state, seemed that peer didn't accept connection.
But if I telnet to the **pod ip** and port that backed the service directly, the connection could be made successfully.
It only happened to one of the service, other services are ok.

And if I scaled the backend pod to a larger value, like 2. Then some of requests to the **service ip** can succeed. It seemed that the service wasn't able to connect to one of the backed pod.

Which component may be the cause of such problem? My service configuration, kube-proxy or flannel?

Comment: report on kubernets: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38802

Answer (score 0):

Check the discussion here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38802

It's required to `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1` on nodes.